# Alarm in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to create a alarm by using the day of the week.

For example if today is Sunday, then my alarm time will be set for Monday.

I tried the below code but is not the correct one:

```
DayOfWeek day = (DayOfWeek)DayOfWeek.Monday;
DateTime beginTime1 =  time.DayOfWeek;
```

Comment: Your code looks really incomplete there.

Comment: Because i am stuck at setting the day to trigger the alarm

Comment: "Incomplete" would be an understatement.

Comment: FYI, you don't have to cast `DayOfWeek.Monday`, it's already an instance of `DayOfWeek`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cast a `DayOfWeek` enumeration to a `Date`. What would you expect the date to be?

Here is an extention method that moves to the next day of the week from a start date:

```
public static DateTimeOffset AddToDayOfWeek(this DateTime start, DayOfWeek day, 
    bool includingToday)
{
    int daysDifference = (int)start.DayOfWeek - (int)day;

    if (daysDifference < 0 || (includingToday && daysDifference == 0))
    {
        daysDifference = 7 - daysDifference;
    }

    return start.AddDays(daysDifference);
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
DateTime nextSunday = DateTime.Today.AddToDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Sunday, false);
```

Comment: You understood enough of the question to get to this answer?  I bow to your divination skills!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DateTime alarm = DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0));
```

where 24 is hours.

or

```
DateTime alarm = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
```

Comment: You can also use `TimeSpan.FromHours(24)` for clarity.

Comment: @Richard Don't like the notation, FromHours doesn't make sense to me, but at least it says hours. :-)